# Excel 2010 Identify Duplicate Rows, Count How Many, Place the Count in existing field, then delete duplicates

Tags: microsoft-excel

I regularly download inventory manifests that are all never the same.  I have been able to automate adding necessary columns, sorting etc to prepare the file for importing into an Access database.  I have one last task.

When three of the same items are on the same pallet, they are listed three times instead of once What I would like to do is remove any duplicates that are on the same pallet id, and replace the number 1 in the Qty field with how many duplicates were found.

I am using excel 2010.

I am attaching a before and after to show what results I am hoping for.

[What it looks like originally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2UtB.jpg)

[What I am hoping for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OqRd.jpg)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add an auxiliary column and enter the formula:

```
=COUNTIF($B$2:$B$18,B2)
```

[image]

Copy the auxiliary column and **Paste as Value**:
[image]

Select the range you need to remove duplicates, go to **Data**- **Remove Duplicates**:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the push in the right direction.  I got it exactly as I was hoping by adding =COUNTIFS($E$2:$E$18,E2,$j$2:$J$18,J2 so that it would calculate how many of the same items were on the same pallet id.